# Is it really an answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I've flagged this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59919987/10306509) as **"Not an answer"**, but my flag was declined: **"declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"**.

I've re-read this answer a couple more times, but still think it's classical additional question to OP posted by user who can't post comments because of the lack of reputation.

Or maybe I understand something wrong and it's really an answer, maybe even a good one?

How can I challenge the declination of this flag?

*Update:* BTW, this answer was [reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25191355) as "Low Quality Posts" after my flag was declined, and was Recommend to Deletion by both reviewers. So maybe they are wrong too?

*Update 2:* Answer I flagged was converted into a comment, but my flag still has status **"declined"**. Is it technically possible to change this status?

*Update 3:* If you don't have enough reputation to view the discussed answer (flagged by me as **"Not an answer"**) after it has been deleted, then here is its FULL text:

> Did you check your python? Is it running outside the notebook?

Comment: Downvote and move on (if you don't want to downvote the post there should be no reason to flag it either)... NAA/VLQ for readable non-donwvoted posts is not guaranteed especially if it looks like it may be an answer (rhetorical question could be an answer). Usual guidance - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I thought it was just an asking for clarification, which should have been a comment. Was I wrong?

Comment: And moderator thought that it's answer (low quality one) that python installation is wrong using rhetorical question... Indeed moderator could have made a mistake... but unless you consistently get NAA flags declined I'd not worry too much. Adjusting bar for "requires expedited removal" (NAA/VLQ flags) may help, but generally downvote take care of such post much faster.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, yes it was one of three flags declined in the last 7 days, and now I've been banned for 7 days because of it. I have not very low overall ratio (213 helpful flags / 13 declined flags including this one), but last days I've got a bad sequence of declinations :( Help page (https://stackoverflow.com/help/declined-flags) says that Meta is my last chance to avoid this ban, so I've asked question about it.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224452/184887

Comment: This is absurd, of course that answer isn't an answer. I'd like to speak to the mod that thinks that's an answer. How does this have -5? *Why is stackoverflow so broken lately?*

Comment: There is no need to be less than constructive. It could be either a mistake, or a genuine disagreement. Mods are entitled to opinions as well. No need get so agitated.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good question for S/O, let alone whatever the answer was.

Comment: @yivi, yes, answer was converted into a comment, but my flag still has status "declined". Do you know, Is it technically possible for anyone to change this status?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I've been banned for 7 days because of it.

Comment: You can't be banned for a single declined flag. You've been banned because you have a number of problematical flags.

Comment: @RobertLongson, It's one of three flags for ban. If this flag would undeclined my ban will be removed. Two flags are not enough for ban and I will be very careful to not get the third flag again.

Comment: "If this flag would undeclined my ban will be removed." - Hardly a moderator will "undecline" a flag. As noted above, it is ultimately a moderator's **opinion** whether a flag is useful (and appropriate action has been taken by the mod) or no. Even correctly flagging a question has a risk of finding the flag declined. This risk is already accounted in a ban condition, like "2 wrong flags is a red zone, but wait until 3 for sure". Actually, there is nothing very bad in flag-ban, just wait for 7 days before continue reviewing.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I have raised 213 helpful flags and have never received such a ban. I think this situation is very unfair :(

Comment: ".. and have never received such a ban." - So you finally got a *new experience* :) And this is not such bad experience: you may treat this ban as "lets relax and stop reviewing". This is what I do when catch the second failed audit during the day.

Comment: I think this is just a mistake. I have flagged many answers like that and never got anyone declined. If we allow a post like that to be considered an answer I think the user auto-moderation will become useless.

Comment: It is *not* possible to retroactively change the status of a flag. Two users (including you) flagged that post as NAA. Two different moderators declined the NAA flags for the same reason. It's fair to assume that neither of them made a mistake. As is probably obvious, though, I disagreed with that, so I converted the answer to a comment, which is what I would have done if I'd been the one who saw/handled your NAA flag. Like everyone has said here multiple times, there is no need to concern yourself over a single declined flag.

Comment: @CodyGray, many thanks for the information about the impossibility of revising the flag status. It's sad that this is the case, but at least I understand the situation now. If you can post your comment as an answer, I can accept it, so it will be more convenient for other users to find it.

Comment: @AdrianMole Your answer (deleted on this Meta post) is good but the last sentence is either a really bad joke or just very inappropriate. I suggest you remove it.